# Wisdom or the wisdom?

Tags: articles

Which sentence is correct?

1. Explore wisdom of the ages with us.
2. Explore **the** wisdom of the ages with us.

Comment: Neither is incorrect.

Comment: @JR I am not sure whether omitting the article is ungrammatical, but it is certainly not idiomatic. I am not saying that "wisdom" always requires an article, but the implication is that the reference here is to a specific body of purported knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

When a singular noun is qualified by a phrase that specifies or identifies it (not just describes it or comments on it), it almost always takes the definite article, even if it is an abstract noun.

Examples:

> The wisdom of the ancients
>
> The experience of sitting an exam
>
> The certainty that you have been there before
>
> the importance of being earnest.

This often applies even to proper nouns:

> The Liverpool that I knew (as opposed to Liverpool as it is today)
>
> The John Brown that I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

2.

Apparently the Body must be at least 30 characters ...

(1.) just doesn't sound right. If I heard it, I'd be presuming they meant *Wisdom of the Ages*, capitalised, and that it was some sort of exhibition in a museum ...